# A simple oscillatory integral with a non-smooth phase

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, asymptotics

Let $\phi\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ be an even function such that $\chi_{(-1/2,1/2)}\le\phi\le \chi_{(-1,1)}$, where $\chi_{(a,b)}$ stands for the indicator function of the interval $(a,b)$. For $\lambda>0$  consider the oscillatory integral
$$
I(\lambda)=\int_\mathbb{R} \phi(x)\, \exp \left(i\lambda(x+\epsilon|x|^{\sqrt{2}})\right)\, dx,
$$
with some fixed (very small) positive constant $\epsilon$.

My question is: what is the asymptotic behavior of this integral as $\lambda\rightarrow \infty$? I can show, by essentially doing careful integration by parts, that the upper bound is $\lesssim \lambda^{-\sqrt{2}}$, but I wonder whether $\lambda^{-\sqrt{2}}$ is also a lower bound?

Note, that if the exponent $\sqrt{2}$ is replaced by $2k$ for some positive integer $k$, then the integral decays like $\lambda^{-M}$ for any $M>0$ due to the non-stationary phase estimate (the derivative of the function $x+\epsilon x^{2k}$ is $\gtrsim 1$).

I would appreciate any hints on how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}\newcommand{\de}{\delta}\newcommand{\ep}{\epsilon}\newcommand{\tI}{\tilde I}$
Take any $a\in(1,2)$ and then any nonzero $\epsilon\in(-1/a,1/a)$. Then
\begin{align*}
    I(t)&:=\int_\mathbb{R} \phi(x)\, \exp(it(x+\epsilon|x|^a))\, dx \\ 
&\sim\frac{2\epsilon\,\Gamma(a+1)}{it^a}\,\sin\frac{\pi a}2 \tag{1}
\end{align*}
as $t\to\infty$. This asymptotics does not depend on $\phi$, as long as
\begin{equation*}
    \phi\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}) \tag{2}
\end{equation*}
is a (not necessarily even) function such that
\begin{equation*}
\chi_{(-1/2,1/2)}\le\phi\le \chi_{(-1,1)}. \tag{3}
\end{equation*}

Indeed, let
\begin{equation*}
    g(x):=x+\ep|x|^a.  
\end{equation*}
Then $g'(x)=1+\ep ax^{[a-1]}$ for real $x\ne0$, where $x^{[c]}:=|x|^{c-1}x$. Therefore and because $|\ep|<1/a$, we see that $2\ge g'\ge1-|\ep|a>0$ on $(-1,1)$. So, there is a unique inverse $h$ of function $g$ on $(-1,1)$ such that for all $x\in(-1,1)$ and all $y\in(g(-1),g(1))$ we have
\begin{equation*}
    y=g(x)\iff x=h(y). \tag{3.5}
\end{equation*}
Also, $g(-x)<0<g(x)$ for all $x\in(0,1)$.

Using now the substitution $g(x)=y$, using conditions (2)--(3) and integrating by parts, we have
\begin{align*}
    I(t)&=\int_\R dx\,\phi(x)\, e^{itg(x)} \\ 
    &=\int_{-1}^1 dx\,\phi(x)\, e^{itg(x)} \\ 
    &=\int_{g(-1)}^{g(1)} dy\,h'(y)\phi(h(y))\, e^{ity} \\ 
    &=-\frac1{it}\,(I_1+\tI_1),   \tag{4}
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
        I_1&:=\int_{g(-1)}^{g(1)} dy\,e^{ity}h''(y)\phi(h(y)), \\ 
        \tI_1&:=\int_{g(-1)}^{g(1)} dy\,e^{ity}h'(y)^2\phi'(h(y)). 
\end{align*}
In view of (2)--(3), $\phi'$ is an (infinitely) smooth function supported on
\begin{equation*}
    S:=[-1,1]\setminus(-1/2,1/2).
\end{equation*}
Hence, $(h')^2\,\phi'\circ h\in C^1(g(S))$. So, integrating by parts, we have
\begin{equation*}
    \tI_1\ll\frac1t; \tag{5}
\end{equation*}
as usual we write $u\ll v$ to mean $|u|\le Cv$ for some real constant $C>0$.
Next, in view of (3),
\begin{equation*}
    I_1=I_2+\tI_2, \tag{6}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{align*}
        I_2&:=\int_{g(-1/2)}^{g(1/2)} dy\,e^{ity}h''(y), \\ 
        \tI_2&:=\int_{g(S)} dy\,e^{ity}h''(y). 
\end{align*}
Note that $h''\in C^1(g(S))$. So, integrating by parts, we have
\begin{equation*}
    \tI_2\ll\frac1t. \tag{7}
\end{equation*}

Writing, for brevity, $x$ for $h(y)$ (cf. (3.5)), we have
\begin{equation*}
    h'(y)=\frac1{1+\ep ah(y)^{[a-1]}}=\frac1{1+\ep ax^{[a-1]}} 
\end{equation*}
and hence
\begin{align*}
        h''(y)&=-\frac{\ep a(a-1)|x|^{a-2}}{(1+\ep ax^{[a-1]})^2},\\  h'''(y)&\ll|x|^{a-3}+|x|^{2a-4}\ll|x|^{a-3}\ll|y|^{a-3} \tag{8}
\end{align*}
for $|x|\le1/2$, that is, for $y\in[g(-1/2),g(1/2)]$. Next, for $y=g(x)\in[g(-1/2),g(1/2)]$ we have $y=x(1+\ep x^{[a-1]})$ and hence
\begin{align*}
    x=h(y)&=\frac y{1+\ep x^{[a-1]}} \\ 
    &=\frac y{1+\ep y^{[a-1]}(1+O(|y|^{a-1}))} \\ 
    &=\frac y{1+\ep y^{[a-1]}} \, (1+O(|y|^{2a-2}) \\  
    &=y\, (1+O(|y|^{a-1})) 
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
        h''(y)&=-\frac{\ep a(a-1)|h(y)|^{a-2}}{(1+\ep ah(y)^{[a-1]})^2}\\     
        &=-\ep a(a-1)|y|^{a-2}[1+O(|y|^{a-1})] \\     
        &=-\ep a(a-1)|y|^{a-2}+O(|y|^{2a-3}).  \tag{9}  
\end{align*}
Further,
\begin{equation*}
    I_2=I_3+\tI_3, \tag{10}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{align*}
        I_3&:=\int_{|y|\le\de} dy\,e^{ity}h''(y), \\ 
        \tI_3&:=\int_{[g(-1/2),g(1/2)]\setminus[-\de,\de]} dy\,e^{ity}h''(y), \\ 
        \de&:=t^{-3/4}.  
\end{align*}
Integrating by parts and using (8) and (9), we have
\begin{align*}
        \tI_3&\ll\frac{|h''(\de)|+|h''(-\de)|+O(1)}t
        +\frac1t\,
        \int_{|y|>\de} dy\,|y|^{a-3}, \\ 
        &\ll \frac{\de^{a-2}}t=t^{1/2-3a/4}=o(t^{1-a}).  
\end{align*}
Using (9) again, we have
\begin{equation*}
    I_3=-\ep a(a-1)I_4+O(\tI_4), \tag{11}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{align*}
        I_4&:=\int_{|y|\le\de} dy\,e^{ity}|y|^{a-2}, \\ 
        \tI_4&:=\int_{|y|\le\de} dy\,|y|^{2a-3}.  
\end{align*}
Next,
\begin{equation*}
    \tI_4\ll\de^{2a-2}=t^{-(2a-2)3/4}=o(t^{1-a}), \tag{12} 
\end{equation*}
\begin{align*}
        I_4&=t^{1-a}\int_{|z|\le t\de} dz\,e^{iz}|z|^{a-2} \\ 
        &=t^{1-a}\int_{|z|\le t^{1/4}} dz\,e^{iz}|z|^{a-2} \\ 
        &\sim t^{1-a}\int_\R dz\,e^{iz}|z|^{a-2}
        =2 t^{1-a}\Gamma(a-1)\sin\frac{\pi a}2.  \tag{13}   
\end{align*}

Collecting the pieces (4)--(7) and (10)--(13), we get the result.

Comment: That's a wonderful answer! Thanks so much, Professor Pinelis!

Comment: I do not see the $i$ at the denominator in (1). $I(t)$ is real if $\phi$ is even and this is in any case true in the asymptotics. Am I wrong?

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune : Thank you for this sanity check. However, I do not see an argument for $I(t)$ to be real even when $\phi$ is even (pun not intended). That would be the case if $g$ were odd. But $g$ is odd only if $\epsilon=0$, in which case the expression after $\sim$ in (1) is $0$ and hence real, even though (1) then loses meaning. Also, I do not see a mistake (do you?) in this proof, except that I now see that I forgot to require $\epsilon$ to be nonzero -- going to fix this now.

Comment: Yes, you are right, no need to be real. But then I do not see why it is purely imaginary! I get almost the same but with $\exp{i a \pi/2}$ instead of $i^{-1}\sin{\pi a/2}$. I did the computations on $(0, \infty)$ instead of the whole line, but this should only mean a factor 2.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune : (i) The complete explanation of why it is purely imaginary is the entire proof, which is pretty long. A short explanation may be this: If $\epsilon=0$, then $g$ is odd and hence $I(t)$ is real, and then $g$ is also smooth and hence $I(t)\to0$ faster than any (say negative) power of $t$. Now, $\epsilon$ is the measure of both the non-oddness and non-smoothness of $g$. Therefore and because $\epsilon$ comes with the factor $i$, it seems natural to expect $I(t)$ to be asymptotically purely imaginary.

Comment: Previous comment continued: (ii) You seem to be suggesting that $\int_\R dz\,e^{iz}|z|^{a-2}=2\int_0^\infty dz\,e^{iz}|z|^{a-2}$, but this is clearly not so.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I think that the difference is due to the fact that I computed the asymptotics of the given integral on $(0, \infty)$, not on the whole line. I get an extra $\sin$. Tomorrow I will check again.

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis I rechecked adding the contribution from $(-\infty,0)$ and I got exactly the same result. Thank you for the discussion. Just a comment; for negative $x$, there is a critical point which leads to a different asymptotic when included in the integration domain. But this you noticed by taking $\epsilon$ small.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune : Thank you for checking the result. As for $\epsilon$, of course, everything will change if the condition $\epsilon\in(-1/a,1/a)$ fails to hold.